# Ajax query string not being posted to ASP.NET controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this Ajax function:

```
UpdateFIConfig: function ($appForm) {

    var valid = $appForm.valid();
    //if not valid the validate plugin will take care of the errors
    if (valid) {

        $appForm.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/IdentifiConfig/DefaultConfiguration/UpdateFIConfig',
            data: $appForm,
            dataType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Error) {
                    cc.jqUtils.openDialog(data.ErrorDescription, 'Error', 'OK', null, null, null);
                } else {
                    window.location.href = '/IdentifiConfig/DefaultConfiguration';
                }
            }
        });

    }
},
```

Which serializes data sent from my view into a query string. I know the data is serialized correctly because I have viewed the string with `console.log($appForm)`, and it's correct.

However, my controller never receives the query string. I have removed a lot of code, but this is basically what the controller function looks like:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UpdateFIConfig(string query)
 {
     NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);

     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(nvc);
 }
```

I receive a null pointer on the line which tries to parse the query string, and I don't know why. Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at the developer tools in chrome or another browser to see what's actually being sent up? If so, does it match your expecations? Have you checked `ModelState.IsValid` inside of your controller action to see if there are any model binding errors occurring?

Comment: No there is no data being sent over the network to the controller, I've already checked the developer console. And yes the model works correctly, I can call other functions and they perform as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same thing ajax in my project the only different is i don't use **dataType**
but **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"**

```
data: "{'query' : '" + $appForm + "'}"
```

Comment: I changed the contentType to what you suggested and now the function isn't even being called.

Comment: also forget since your variable in controller call query data should be like this

data: "{'query' : '" + $appForm + "'}",

Comment: Man, if I could give you a thousand dollars right now I would. Thank you, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

This bit:

```
$appForm.serialize();
```

Returns a `string` that you're never using. `serialize` won't actually modify the form. You should assign it to a variable and pass that up instead:

```
var data = $appForm.serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: '/IdentifiConfig/DefaultConfiguration/UpdateFIConfig',
    data: data,
    /* etc */
});
```

Comment: Ok. now I see the correct data being sent up to the network in the developer console, but the function still doesn't receive anything. Could it be something with my `dataType`?

Comment: @TobyCaulk: `dataType` is the type of data you're expecing *back* from the server. You might try `contentType: text/plain` since you don't want the string processed at all by jQuery (at least I don't think you do)

Comment: Still nothing in the controller function unfortunately.

Comment: @TobyCaulk: When debugging, what happens if you inspect `ModelState.IsValid`? Does it return true?

Comment: @TobyCaulk: I'm actually seeing the same behavior in a test project. Let me fiddle around with it and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but I get around this annoyance by accepting an Object with a string property instead of just a string. So do something like:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UpdateFIConfig(MyTypeWithQry query)
 { ...
```

and

```
    $.ajax({ url: '/IdentifiConfig/DefaultConfiguration/UpdateFIConfig',
             data: { 'query' : $appForm },
             dataType: 'application/json',
...
```

Comment: I'll try this, but why does it happen? Do you know?

Comment: @TobyCaulk No, I don't know. I suspect something to do with the Content-Type and the content being mismatched or something. You could experiment with text/plain instead of application/json.